# Summernote Icons Missing in Rails Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production-environment, summernote, rails-assets

I have implemented Summernote in my rails app. Everything works fine in development and the Summernote icons are displayed properly. However, when I deployed it to production, those icons are missing. I have tried to run

```
rake assets:clean
```

and

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

but those icons still missing. Even I have added these

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.1/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

still no luck. Does anybody have this issue?

Comment: check this https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/1781